# How do I format the output from changeset using paper_trail in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

```
# reports\workorder_version.html.haml
%table
%class='Work Orders'
  %tr
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Index
      %th Date
      %th User ID
      %th Event
      %th Item Type
      %th Item ID
      %th Change Set
      %th IP Address
    %tr

  %tbody
    - workorder = Workorder.where(:id => params[:id]).first
    - workorder.versions.reverse.each do |version|
      %tr
        %td= version.index
        %td= version.created_at.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
        %td= Employee.find(version.whodunnit.to_i).full_name.upcase
        %td= version.event.humanize
        %td= version.item_type.humanize
        %td= version.item_id
        %td= version.changeset.to_s.humanize
        %td= version.ip
```

My output:

[image: Output of my report[1]]

How do I make the output easier for the end user to read?

Comment: version.changeset is a method from the paper_trail gem. I need to be able to format the output to make it easy for the end user to read, it's showing the changes made to an item and the time it was created and last updated. It is a hash, but how do I check to find out what keys it has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is from [`version.changeset`, which returns a hash](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions). You can loop through the hash to display each field and its changes on separate lines like so:

```
%td
  -version.changeset.each do |field, value|
    = field + ": "
    = value
    %br
```

Comment: That returns "can't convert Array into String". And if I convert it to a string nothing buy # is displayed. And when I goto inspect element in the browser I get: "  #  " <enumerator:0xbd2aedc>      </enumerator:0xbd2aedc>

Comment: Using logger.info I figured out it's a hash with an array: {"job_category_id"=>[2462, 2460], "updated_at"=>[2015-10-08 13:48:09 UTC, 2015-10-08 18:45:50 UTC]}

Comment: Yes of course, that's the same output you see in the question :) Did the edit work? ERB should display the value as an array. Do you want to display it not as an array? How do you want to display it?

Comment: I just checked the edit and that did work :) It's a good start! How would I omit the updated_at?

Comment: You could add `next if field == "updated_at"` just after the `each` line.

Comment: thanks you've been very helpful. I now need to make a model that will display job cateegory names in place of their ids as displayed above. Any thoughts or code examples as to how I can accomplish this? And should I start a new thread for this?

Comment: You should start a new question, that sounds relatively complicated. Feel free to link here if it helps. Also please accept the answer if it helped you.